# Allow line break at @ in email with xurl package LaTeX

Tags: urls, xurl

I need to allow line breaks in email addresses in LaTeX. I used to do that using the `url` package, and the adresses broke on the @, which was acceptable.

I recently switched to using `xurl` for linebreaking in other URLs (not email addresses) and noticed that, once I did so, my email addresses broke at whichever character was on the margin. This makes sense because `xurl` allows line breaks at any alphanumeric character, but I would like LaTeX to prefer line breaking at @ for email addresses and only break elsewhere if necessary. I have looked at other answers on this site and other resources online, but I can only find instructions to use those packages to permit linebreaking, not instructions about how to create a preference for line breaks at @ (`url` package style) over line breaks elsewhere (enabled by `xurl`).

In case an MWE is useful, I would like to mirror this output:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{2in}
\url{sample_username@lengthydomain.com}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

But with the `xurl` package enabled (because I need it elsewhere in the file to solve a different problem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the manual, you can use the old settings with `\useOriginalUrlSetting` inside a group:

```
{\useOriginalUrlSetting\url{sample_username@lengthydomain.com}}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps s.th. like this does the trick:

```latex
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
                     \newcommand*\@printemailaddressUrlLeftCopy{}%
                     \newcommand\AtIfhyperrefloaded[2]{#1}%
                   }{%
                     \newcommand\AtIfhyperrefloaded[2]{#2}%
                   }%
  \@ifpackageloaded{url}{}{\RequirePackage{url}}%
  \@ifdefinable\printemailaddress{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\printemailaddress{%
      \leavevmode\begingroup
      \let\do\@makeother \dospecials \catcode`{\@ne  \catcode`}\tw@  \catcode`\ =10  \catcode`\#=6 %
      \@ifstar{%
                \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@gobble
                \expandafter\@gobbletwo\@printemailaddress
              }{%
                \AtIfhyperrefloaded{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstofone}%
                                   {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@gobble}%
                \expandafter\@gobbletwo\@printemailaddress
              }%
    }%
  }%
  \DeclareUrlCommand\@printemailaddress{%
    {%
      \let\@printemailaddressUrlLeftCopy= \UrlLeft
      \def\UrlLeft##1\UrlRight{\href{mailto:##1}{\@printemailaddressUrlLeftCopy ##1\UrlRight}}%
    }%
    \def\UrlBreaks{\do\\\do\/\do\!\do\_\do\|\do\;\do\>\do\]%
                   \do\)\do\,\do\?\do\&\do\'\do+\do\=\do\#\do:%
                   \do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j\do\k\do\l%
                   \do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t\do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z%
                   \do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D\do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K\do\L%
                   \do\M\do\N\do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U\do\V\do\W\do\X\do\Y\do\Z%
                   \do0\do1\do2\do3\do4\do5\do6\do7\do8\do9}%
    \edef\UrlSpecials{%
      \unexpanded\expandafter{\UrlSpecials
        \do\@{\hbox{\string @}\hfil\penalty\numexpr\UrlBreakPenalty-206\relax\hfilneg}%
        \do\.{\hbox{\string .}\hfil\penalty\numexpr\UrlBreakPenalty-205\relax\hfilneg}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xurl}

\begin{document}

%\urlstyle{same}
\urlstyle{tt}

\twocolumn

\begin{minipage}{2in}
text \url{sample_username@lengthydomain.com} text 
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\hrule

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{2in}%
text \printemailaddress{sample_username@l.com} text
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{2in}%
text \printemailaddress{sample_username@le.com} text
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{2in}%
text \printemailaddress{sample_username@len.com} text
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{2in}%
text \printemailaddress{sample_username@leng.com} text
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{2in}%
text \printemailaddress{sample_username@lengt.com} text
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{2in}%
text \printemailaddress{sample_username@length.com} text
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{2in}%
text \printemailaddress{sample_username@lengthy.com} text
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{2in}%
text \printemailaddress{sample_username@lengthyd.com} text
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{2in}%
text \printemailaddress{sample_username@lengthydo.com} text
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{2in}%
text \printemailaddress{sample_username@lengthydom.com} text
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{2in}%
text \printemailaddress{sample_username@lengthydoma.com} text
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{2in}%
text \printemailaddress{sample_username@lengthydomai.com} text
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{2in}%
text \printemailaddress{sample_username@lengthydomain.com} text
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{2in}%
text \printemailaddress{sample_username.something.else@nice.weirdlengthy.lengthydomainlengthydomainlengthydomain.com} text
\end{minipage}

\newpage

\begin{minipage}{2in}
text \csname \AtIfhyperrefloaded{nolink}{}url\endcsname{sample_username@lengthydomain.com} text
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\hrule

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{2in}%
text \printemailaddress*{sample_username@l.com} text
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{2in}%
text \printemailaddress*{sample_username@le.com} text
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{2in}%
text \printemailaddress*{sample_username@len.com} text
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{2in}%
text \printemailaddress*{sample_username@leng.com} text
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{2in}%
text \printemailaddress*{sample_username@lengt.com} text
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{2in}%
text \printemailaddress*{sample_username@length.com} text
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{2in}%
text \printemailaddress*{sample_username@lengthy.com} text
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{2in}%
text \printemailaddress*{sample_username@lengthyd.com} text
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{2in}%
text \printemailaddress*{sample_username@lengthydo.com} text
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{2in}%
text \printemailaddress*{sample_username@lengthydom.com} text
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{2in}%
text \printemailaddress*{sample_username@lengthydoma.com} text
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{2in}%
text \printemailaddress*{sample_username@lengthydomai.com} text
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{2in}%
text \printemailaddress*{sample_username@lengthydomain.com} text
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{2in}%
text \printemailaddress*{sample_username.something.else@nice.weirdlengthy.lengthydomainlengthydomainlengthydomain.com} text
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]